# installing wine produces error about my internet connection 

Tags: wine

I have downloaded wine successfully using software center.

When I click install it gives me an error - Some unrestricted softwares needs to be installed and there is an error with my internet connection.

How many times do i need to download this wine? I am confused, greatly confused.

Comment: paste the error messages here

Comment: what are the unrestricted softwares that need installin'?

Comment: I think it is untrusted not unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

Open
Software sources and check all repositories

open the update manager and press check button

Then press install button in the software centre

Comment: hey I first press check button then do i install the updates or do i go directly software centre and install wine?

Comment: Yeah,after finishing this oprn goto software centre

Comment: Failed to download package files , Check your internet connection is the error i am getting and i am connected

Comment: Failed to download package files